# How to implement binary Search process in Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search

I have no idea how to implement binary Search process in Arraylist in Java.

There are two arraylist showing airport Names and routes between two airport Names.

Here are airportName and Route Class defined below.

```
public class AirportName{
    private String airportName;
}

public class Route{
    private String takeOffPoint;
    private String landingPoint;
}
```

Airport Names are defined an abbreviation of Airport Names like (JFK) in Arraylist 
Route names are defined a route object including take off point and landing point in Arraylist like 
(JFK - TLV)

Because there are a lot of airport Names and routes in each arraylist whose size is above 30000, I have to use binary search to implement optimization of code.

I've already done the process without the usage of binary search.

How can I do it via binary search?

Here is my code snippet shown below.

```
ArrayList<AirportName> airportNames = ShowProcess.getAirports();
ArrayList<Route> routeNamesList = ShowProcess.getAirportRoutes();
```

Airpot Names

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter AirportName : ");
    String airportName = sc.nextLine(); 

    boolean checkAirportNameValid = false;

    for(AirportName airport : airportNames) {
        if(airport.getAirportName().equals(airportName)) {
            checkAirportNameValid = true;
        }
    }
```

Route Names

```
public static ArrayList<String> searchProcess(String airportName, ArrayList<Route> routeNamesList) {
        ArrayList<String> destinationNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Route route : routeNamesList) {
            if(route.getTakeOffPoint().equals(airportName)) {
                destinationNames.add(route.getLandingPoint());
            }
        }

        return destinationNames;
}
```

Comment: Is your list pre-sorted?

Comment: @user It's kind a linear search but I have to use binary search to search item in the list because of its long size.

Comment: Okay, but is your list already sorted?

Comment: @user It's not sorted.

Comment: Then binary search is probably not worth it. Linear search is O(n), binary search is O(nlogn) (more actually)

Comment: @user ok but I have to do it via binary search.

Comment: Then you will have to sort the list first. Which will be `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: Hey, this looks good, but as others have pointed out, binary search only works if you have a sorted, so you will have to sort it, which technically is then slower than a linear search: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/a/binary-search

Comment: @Harshal Parekh How can I do it via binary search. I have to use it in this program.

Comment: @xdhmoore I agree with you but I need to use binary search n this program. How can I do it

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot help you implement an entire program or feature. However, if you follow whatever resources you find online, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: @Tony Brand First sort it, then you can do binary search on it. It's not the most efficient way, but it sounds like this a homework assignment or something so it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @xdhmoore it's not any kind of homework. What I just to do is to learn how to implement binary search in the function.

Comment: @TonyBrand - feel free to ask new questions, but please don't @ people on old questions to get help on new ones. Hope you figured our your new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. It works

```
public static Integer[] binarySearch(ArrayList<Route> routeNamesList, Comparable key) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int lo = 0, hi = routeNamesList.size() - 1, mid;
        routeNamesList.sort((str1, str2) -> str1.getTakeOffPoint().compareTo(str2.getTakeOffPoint()));

        while (lo <= hi) {
            mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            int cmp = key.compareTo(routeNamesList.get(mid).getTakeOffPoint());
            if (cmp == 0) {
                int lowerBoundary = lowerIndex(routeNamesList, key, lo, mid);
                int upperBoundary = upperIndex(routeNamesList, key, mid, hi);
                for(int i = lowerBoundary; i <= upperBoundary; i++) {
                    arrList.add(i);
                }
                break;
            } else if (cmp < 0)
                hi = mid - 1;
            else
                lo = mid + 1;
        }
        return arrList.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }

    public static int lowerIndex(ArrayList<Route> routeNamesList, Comparable key, int lo, int hi) {
        int mid;
        int lastMatch = hi;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            int cmp = key.compareTo(routeNamesList.get(mid).getTakeOffPoint());
            if (cmp == 0) {
                lastMatch = mid;
                hi = mid - 1;
            } else if (cmp < 0) {
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        return lastMatch;
    }

    public static int upperIndex(ArrayList<Route> routeNamesList, Comparable key, int lo, int hi) {
        int mid;
        int lastMatch = lo;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            int cmp = key.compareTo(routeNamesList.get(mid).getTakeOffPoint());
            if (cmp == 0) {
                lastMatch = mid;
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else if (cmp < 0) {
                hi = mid - 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        return lastMatch;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> searchProcess(String airportName, ArrayList<Route> routeNamesList) {
        ArrayList<String> destinationNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        Integer[] indices = binarySearch(routeNamesList, airportName);
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
            if(routeNamesList.get(i).getTakeOffPoint().equals(airportName)) {
                destinationNames.add(routeNamesList.get(i).getLandingPoint());
            }
        }

        return destinationNames;
    }
```